# Calling a Java function with a JavaScript variable inside a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I need help. I need to call a Java function "getLocCountByWhId()" in a Java class; this Java function is being called within a JavaScript in a for-loop. I need to pass in a JavaScript variable as a parameter into this Java function "getLocCountByWhId()". I have been struggling for a week and reading numerous website to get some guidelines but I have not been able to resolve the problem. Thank you in advance for your help. The code is listing below:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function onCreatePO()
{
    <%long jspAllocId = alloc.getId();%>;
    var recItemId = ""; // Local variable for item id.
    var recWhId = ""; // Local variable for warehouse id.                           

    for (var i=0, j=document.what_if_summary.elements.length; i<j; i++)
    {      
       var recStr = document.what_if_summary.elements[i].value; 
       var splitStr = new Array(); 
       splitStr = recStr.split('^');
       recItemId = splitStr[1]; // Get the field value for Item_ID.
       recWhId = splitStr[2]; // Get the field value for Warehouse_ID.

// Get a database connection with global 'conn' object and retrieve store count.
       <%AfsGetVDSCountByWarehouseBean.setConnection(conn);%>; 

// The below assignment from JavaScript variable to JSP variable do not work 
// because of a second JavaScript tag. How can I get around this ?

//<% String jspItemId = "<script>document.writeln(recItemId)</script>"; %>
//<% String jspWhId = "<script>document.writeln(recWhId)</script>"; %>

   currentStoreCount = <%= AfsGetVDSCountByWarehouseBean.getLocCountByWhId(jspAllocId, jspItemId, jspWhId)%>;
   }
}

//-->
</script>

// I get this example of assigning Javascript to JSP variable but I got double tag problem.
<script>
var v="Roseindia";
</script>
<% String st="<script>document.writeln(v)</script>";
out.println("value="+st); %>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not possible, and (sorry!) reflects a basic misunderstanding as to how server-side code such as JSP (or ASP, PHP, etc) works.

A JSP page is basically a Java servlet *running on the web server* that dynamically generates a web page and returns it to the browser. The resulting web page may contain HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc., but to the Java code all of that is just text. The Java/JSP code cannot understand or interact with the JavaScript because the JavaScript doesn't run on the web server, it is just more text to be sent as part of the response back to the browser.

When the browser gets the response it will display the web page and execute any JavaScript.

Further reading (I wouldn't put too much faith in what you read at the RoseIndia site):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-introjsp/

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/servlets-jsp-140445.html

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JSPIntro/

Comment: From "AndrewHac": Thank you for your answer. Is there any other method out there that I can use to call my Java class "getStoreCount(JS1, JS2, JS3)" with JS1, 2, 3 being JavaScript ?. I need to call the SQL SELECT statement inside this "getStoreCount()" Java function. I read on the Internet that you can use request.getParameter() to pass in the JS var to the JSP var, can I use this ?. Thank you again in advance.

Comment: If you have code running in the browser that needs to get data from the web server there are two common ways to do it: (1) Submit the client data in a form, let the server process it and return a new page to the client (which from the user's view means a page refresh), in which case you'll probably store the values from the JS vars in hidden form fields for submission and use `request.getParameter()` within your JSP to get the values; (2) Use Ajax, in which case your JS can submit a request without navigating to a new page - can't fit an explanation of Ajax here. Read the JSP tutorials above.